# grep for "term" and exclude "another term"

Tags: linux, bash, search, grep

I am trying to build a grep search that searches for a term but exludes lines which have a second term. I wanted to use multiple `-e "pattern"` options but that has not worked.

Here is an example of a command I tried and the error message it generated.

```
grep -i -E "search term" -ev "exclude term"
grep: exclude term: No such file or directory
```

It seams to me that the `-v` applies to all search terms / patterns. As this runs but then does not include `search term` in results.

```
grep -i -E "search term" -ve "exclude term"
```

Comment: Is there any other option for exclude, as sometimes we have to grep lines around a word  and If we exclude in the next operation using '|' , it just removes that word but doesn't remove the block for that word

Answer (score 60, accepted):

To *and* expressions with grep you need two invocations:

```
grep -Ei "search term" | grep -Eiv "exclude term"
```

If the terms you are searching for are not regular expressions, use fixed string matching (`-F`) which is faster:

```
grep -F "search term" | grep -Fv "exclude term"
```

Answer (score 25):

Short of invoking grep twice, there is only one way I can think of to accomplish this. It involves [Perl Compatible Regular Expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions) (PCRE) and some rather hacky [look-around assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

To search for **foo** excluding matches that contain **bar**, you can use:

```
grep -P '(?=^((?!bar).)*$)foo'
```

Here's how it works:

- `(?!bar)` matches anything that not **bar** without consuming characters from the string. Then `.` consumes a single character.
- `^((?!bar).)*` repeats the above from the start of the string (`^`) to  the end of it (`$`). It will fail if `bar` is encountered at any given point, since `(?!bar)` will not match.
- `(?=^((?!bar).)*$)` makes sure the string matches the previous pattern, without consuming characters from the string.
- `foo` searches for **foo** as usual.

I found this hack in [Regular expression to match string not containing a word?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/406230). In [Bart Kiers' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/406408), you can find a much more detailed explanation of how the negative look-ahead operates.

Comment: Nice hack. This trick works in Java too, btw.

Comment: This will not work as the regex only matches lines starting with `foo`, and not containing `foo`. A working (and better performing) regex solution would be `grep -P '(?=^(?!.*bar).*foo)'`

Answer (score 18):

### If you want to do this in one pass, you can use awk instead of grep.

Format:

`echo "some text" | awk '/pattern to match/ && !/pattern to exclude/'`

Examples:

- `echo "hello there" | awk '/hello/ && !/there/'`

Returns nothing.

- `echo "hello thre" | awk '/hello/ && !/there/'`

Returns: hello thre

- `echo "hllo there" | awk '/hello/ && !/there/'`

Returns nothing.

### For multiple patterns, you can use parenthesis to group them.

Examples:

- `echo "hello thre" | awk '(/hello/ || /hi/) && !/there/'`

Returns: hello thre

- `echo "hi thre" | awk '(/hello/ || /hi/) && !/there/'`

Returns: hi thre

- `echo "hello there" | awk '(/hello/ || /hi/) && !/there/'`

Returns nothing.

- `echo "hi there" | awk '(/hello/ || /hi/) && !/there/'`

Returns nothing.

Comment: It worked for me, but I lost the colors =P

Comment: Colors from what output?

If you are trying to preserve colors with ls, use the "--color=always" argument whenever parsing the output (or you will normally always lose the colors when parsing the text).  Example:  `ls --color=always | awk '/hello/ && !/goodbye/'`

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Philip! I tried that before, but without success. I guess that as the pattern has the colored text, it doesn't match later, and I should include some kind of color code in the pattern. Anyway, yours is the fastest way that I found to do `grep -R` in several code files using Ubuntu command line.

Comment: history  | awk '/pattern1|pattern2/ && !/pattern3|pattern4/'

Answer (score 3):

The **-v (or --invert-match)** option filters out matches.

You can make use of `grep` along with `pipe` to grep for term and exclude another.

```
grep pattern1 *.txt | grep -v pattern2
```

Matches all lines in `"*.txt"` files containing `pattern1`, but ***not*** `pattern2`.

Answer (score 2):

From my experiments it does not seam to make much difference if you pipe your exclude terms
through `grep` or `sed`. Sed has some other useful text replacement features which I often use to better filter the out put of log files. So I am going to use sed as I combine quite a number of filters on sed.

```
wc /var/log/tomcat/tomcat.2013-01-14.log.1 
  1851725

 /usr/bin/time grep -i -E "(loginmanager)" /var/log/tomcat/tomcat.2013-01-14.log.1 | sed -e "/login OK/d" -e "/Login expired/d" | wc
24.05user 0.15system 0:25.27elapsed 95%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 3504maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+246minor)pagefaults 0swaps
   5614   91168 1186298

 /usr/bin/time grep -i -E "(loginmanager)" /var/log/tomcat/tomcat.2013-01-14.log.1 | sed -e "/login OK/d" -e "/Login expired/d" | wc
23.50user 0.16system 0:24.48elapsed 96%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 3504maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+246minor)pagefaults 0swaps
   5614   91168 1186298

 /usr/bin/time grep -i -E "(loginmanager)" /var/log/tomcat/tomcat.2013-01-14.log.1 | grep -v -e "login OK" -e "Login expired" | wc
23.08user 0.14system 0:23.55elapsed 98%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 3504maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+246minor)pagefaults 0swaps
   5614   91168 1186298

 /usr/bin/time grep -i -E "(loginmanager)" /var/log/tomcat/tomcat.2013-01-14.log.1 | grep -v -e "login OK" -e "Login expired" | wc
23.50user 0.15system 0:25.27elapsed 93%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 3488maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+245minor)pagefaults 0swaps
   5614   91168 1186298
```

Comment: Try comparing the runtime of `grep -F` instead of `grep -E` and don't use `-i` if you don't need it.

Comment: But then you don't provide examples using `sed` ;)