# Creating a Regex expression with a “not” condition for a specific substring

Tags: regex

I have a use case where I am searching for a particular sub string in a string and if that particular string contains another particular sub string I want it to be rejected.

Ex:

1. `pikachu_is_the_best_ever_in_the_world_go_pikachu`
2. `mew_is_the_best_ever_in_the_world_go_mew`
3. `raichu_is_the_best_ever_in_the_world_go_raichu`

I want my Regex expression to pick up the string having the word "best" and not the word "mew", i.e the first and third string.

I have tried combining `^(.*best).*$` and `^((?!mew).)*$` into the below expressions and the second regex one only ignores words if "mew" is present in the start of the string.

```
^(.*best)((?!mew).).*$
```

And have tried

```
^((?!mew).)(.*best).*$
```

Comment: So you’re looking for lines that contain string1 but not string2? Try to write questions simply and clearly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [grep for "term" and exclude "another term"](https://superuser.com/questions/537619/grep-for-term-and-exclude-another-term)

Comment: Sorry this is my first time posting a question. I am trying to write a regex pattern to pick the string that contains the word best and also not contain mew.

Comment: I cannot use if /else , the application I am working on uses plain  regex in its inner logic to find keywords.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Find what: `^(?=.*best)(?:(?!mew).)*$`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Search in document</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           : start of line
(?=         : positive lookahead
  .*        : 0 or more any character but newline
  best      : literally "best"
)           : end lookahead
(?:         : start non capture group
  (?!       : negative lookahead, make sure we don't have 
    mew     : literally "mew"
  )         : end lookahead
  .         : any character but newline
)*          : group may appear 0 or more times
$           : end of line
```

Comment: I didn't quite understood the last `.` - why it's needed there? I would expect that it's for matching another char after `mew` - but it won't work without it, even if `mew` is the last thing before the end of the line.

Comment: @arieljannai: Because you need to match that there is no `mew` at any place within the string, It checks from the beginning of the line that there is not `mew` followed by 1 character, then iterate (`*`) all along the string, until the end of string.

Comment: @Toto You sir are a genius , it worked brilliantly. Thank you everyone for your time helping me out really appreciate it.